# SQL Server 2005 and Windows Server 2003 - Cluster Logs

Tags: windows-server-2003, cluster

We have a active/active failover cluster. I am trying to find out if one of my resource group (SQL Server 2005) was automatically/manually flipped to another node at a given point of time. I have looked into:

c:\Windows\Cluster

C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\Cluster

Any help on this is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

-Subhash

Answer (score 1):

Check your event log.  You should see it there.